# text box value won't updated using data bind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, textbox

In order to prevent long discussion in the comment section I'm asking it again.

I have a `TextBox` which is bound to an object.

When I'm changing the object value, the `TextBox` text value won't change.

I read all most each discussion exist here about this and didn't figure it out.

XAML:

```
<TabItem Header="תלמידים" Name="Tabstudents" >
            <Grid Height="757" Margin="0">
                <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Height="450" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,0,11,287" Name="brdrStudents" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto">
                    <Grid Height="441">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtblkStudenName" Text="שם פרטי:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,0,400" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtblkStudenNotes" Text="שם משפחה:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,00,0,360" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtBlkStudenTecher" Text="תעודת זהות:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,0,320" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtblkStudenAdress" Text="כתובת:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,0,120" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtBlkStudenPrice" Text="טלפון בית:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,0,280" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtblkStudenPicForm" Text="אישור צילום:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="460,0,0,400" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtBlkStudenDates" Text="טלפון סלולרי:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,0,240" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtblkStudenMedical" Text="בעיות רפואיות:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="460,0,0,320" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtBlkStudenDivideMoney" Text="טלפון הורים:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,0,200" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtblkStudenParentsConf" Text="אישור הורים:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="460,0,0,360" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtBlkStudenPlace" Text="שמות ההורים:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,0,160" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtblkStudenBirth" Text="תאריך לידה:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,0,80" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Height="33" Name="txtblkStudenClasses" Text="רשימת חוגים:" Width="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="663,0,0,280" />
                        <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1006,0,0,400" Name="txtBlkPayments" Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Text="תשלומים:" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="159" />

                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,0,0,400" Name="txtStudenName" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" >
                            <TextBox.Text>
                                <Binding NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" Path="firstName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                                </Binding>
                            </TextBox.Text>
                        </TextBox>
                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,0,0,360" Name="txtStudenLastName" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" >
                            <TextBox.Text>
                                <Binding NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" Path="lastName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                                </Binding>
                            </TextBox.Text>
                        </TextBox>
                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,0,0,320" Name="txtStudenID" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" >
                            <TextBox.Text>
                                <Binding NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" Path="studentID" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                                </Binding>
                            </TextBox.Text>
                        </TextBox>
                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,0,0,120" Name="txtStudenAdress" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding lastName}"/>
                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,0,0,280" Name="txtStudenHomePhone" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding homePhone}"/>
                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,0,0,240" Name="txtStudenCellPhone" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding cellPhone}"/>
                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="614,0,0,320" Name="txtStudenMedical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding medProblems}"/>
                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,0,0,200" Name="txtStudenParentsPhone" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding parentsPhone}"/>
                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,0,0,160" Name="txtStudenParentsName" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding parentsName}"/>
                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,0,0,80" Name="txtStudenBirthDay" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding birthDate}"/>

                        <Button Content="ערוך תלמיד" Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,0,0,10" Name="btnEditStuden" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="118" />
                        <Button Content="הוסף תלמיד" Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,10" Name="btnAddStuden" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="118" />
                        <Button Content="מחק תלמיד" Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="254,0,0,10" Name="btnDeleteStudent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="118" />
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}" Content="הבא" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="633,0,0,6" Name="btnStudenNext" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75"/>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}" Content="הקודם" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="552,0,0,6" Name="btnStudenPrev" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75"/>

                        <ListBox Height="207" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="614,0,0,80" Name="lstBxClasses" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=classesList.className}"/>


                        <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="913,0,0,260" Name="txtBlkDebt" Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Text="יתרת חשבון:" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="131" />

                        <Rectangle Height="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="913,0,0,400" Name="rectangle2" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="312" />
                        <Rectangle Height="426" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="900,0,0,10" Name="rectangle3" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="333" />
                        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="False" Margin="909,0,0,226" Name="txtDebt" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="312" />
                        <Button Content="הרשם לחוג" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="909,0,0,20" Name="btnPay" Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="312" Click="btnPay_Click" />
                        <CheckBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="614,15,0,0" Name="cbPicConf" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" Width="38" BorderThickness="1" IsChecked="{Binding isPicFormExists}" IsEnabled="False" />
                        <CheckBox BorderThickness="1" FontSize="24" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="614,51,0,0" Name="cbParentsConf" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38" IsChecked="{Binding isParentsConfExists}" IsEnabled="False" />

                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Label Content="רשימת תלמידים" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="18,0,30,234" Name="lblStudentsList" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="1208" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" />
                <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,0,0,196" Name="textBlock1" Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Text="שם פרטי:" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="159" />
                <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="492,0,0,192" Name="textBlock2" Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Text="תעודת זהות:" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="159" />
                <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="True" Margin="219,0,0,192" Name="txtFindFirstName" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" />
                <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="True" Margin="638,0,0,192" Name="txtFindID" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" />
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="126" Name="dgStudents" Width="1157" Margin="25,0,74,64" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="dgStudents_SelectionChanged">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="שם פרטי" Width="175" Binding="{Binding firstName}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="שם משפחה" Width="175" Binding="{Binding lastName}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="תעודת זהות" Width="175" Binding="{Binding studentID}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="תאריך לידה" Width="175" Binding="{Binding birthDate}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="מאזן חשבון" Width="175" Binding="{Binding accountBalance}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="טלפון - בית" Width="175" Binding="{Binding homePhone}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="טלפון סלולרי" Width="175" Binding="{Binding cellPhone}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="טלפון - הורים" Width="175" Binding="{Binding parentsPhone}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="שם ההורים" Width="175" Binding="{Binding parentsName}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="כתובת" Width="175" Binding="{Binding adress}" />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="טופס אישור צילום" Width="175" Binding="{Binding isPicFormExists}" />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="טופס אישור הורים" Width="175" Binding="{Binding isParentsConfExists}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="בעיות רפואיות" Width="175" Binding="{Binding medProblems}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

Codebehind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private student _selectedStudent;

    public student selectedStudent  // This is the object
    {
        get { return _selectedStudent; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedStudent)
            {
                _selectedStudent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("_selectedStudent");
            }
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
            InitializeComponent();

            selectedStudent = clsLoadStudent();
            this.DataContext = selectedStudent;  // Here I use the object as a datacontext.
    }
    private void dgStudents_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedStudent = new student();
        selectedStudent = (student)dgStudents.SelectedItem;


    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) // if there is any subscribers
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I have been told to implement `OnPropertyChanged`. I did, I think.

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("_selectedStudent");` should be `OnPropertyChanged("selectedStudent");`.

Comment: In debug do you see OnPropertyChanged called when you assign selectedStudent?  Is firstName a public property?

Comment: LPL - changed. same problem. Blam - Yes and Yes.. Same problem.

Comment: And you call `OnPropertyChanged("firstName");` not with underscore?

Comment: LPL - Yes, same problem. Value of the text box wo'nt change..

Comment: You set DataContext to selectedStudent but I guess you are using ListBox, ListView or DataGrid. Then DataContext should be a list of students (or an object with this list). Does TextBox ever show right value? Any binding errors? Why is selectedStudent not bound to dgStudents.SelectedItem? Should be easier. And why you create a new student in dgStudents_SelectionChanged if you assign after that dgStudents.SelectedItem?

Comment: You right. I'm using datagrid which loads a list of objects (student). As you seggusted I set the textbox dataContext to dgStudens.SelectedItem. Now it wo'nt evene show the first value. its empty. the datagrid is not empty.

Comment: Don't set the DataContext for TextBox. Set DataContext for dgStudents or window/usercontrol to the list of students. Then every item in dgStudents control will have automatically a student as DataContext.

Comment: But now, when I choose a different student in the datagrid - the text box value still won't change. I tried to add txt.dataContext = dg.selectedItem. No change..

Comment: Again. Don't set DataContext for TextBox or in dgStudents_SelectionChanged. For better help you should post more xaml that we can see the structure (especially where is the TextBox, where the DataGrid).

Comment: edited my question with the full xaml

Comment: Many ways (for improvements). Simplest I think is binding DataContext of Border to dgStudents.SelectedItem. `<Border DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=dgStudents}" Name="brdrStudents" ...` and remove `dgStudents_SelectionChanged` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `MainWindow` class which is correct, but you are using the `DataContext` as the property name as your code suggests (which would not work and could be the reason your binding is not working):

```
//Below DataContext binding needs to be changed, you are binding directly to property, instead you should bind to you MainWindow object
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        selectedStudent = clsLoadStudent();
        //this.DataContext = selectedStudent;  // Does not work
        this.DataContext = this;  // Correct way           
}
```

Then, you should change `Textbox` Text property binding to point to properties in your `student` object property as below (selectedStudent.FirstName):

```
<TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,0,0,400" Name="txtStudenName" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="240" IsEnabled="False" Text={Binding selectedStudent.FirstName, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}/>
```

Also, you should raise the propertychanged event for the property name:

```
OnPropertyChanged("selectedStudent");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, then I would recommend that you define a `DependencyProperty` to bind to instead:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StudentProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("Student", typeof(Student), typeof(MainWindow), new 
    UIPropertyMetadata(100.0));

public Student Student
{
    get { return (Student)GetValue(StudentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StudentProperty, value); }
}
```

Then, you must set your `DataContext`... the easiest (but not best) way is to do this in the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Student = new Student() { FirstName = "John", OtherProperty = "Something else" };
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Now bind to a property from your `Student` object (assuming you have a property in there named `FirstName`):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Student.FirstName}" />
```

Comment: I didnt understand. When do I assign a value for the object?

Comment: You can do that where ever and when ever you feel like it... I updated my answer, adding it into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `DataContext` again:

```
private void dgStudents_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedStudent = new student();
        DataContext = (student)dgStudents.SelectedItem;
    }
```

Comment: Well, it solved the problem if I'll do: txt.dataContext = dg.selectedItem. For each textbox. I thought databinding supose to prevent things like this... ??

Comment: Window is on the top level of the textBox. If you don't set DataContext of the textBox it will try to use one of the parent Control => Grid=>Grid=>TabItem .... Window.
As you set this.DataContex in your code, you are setting DataContext of the Window so it can be used by other Controls as well (textBox).
My code should work as well.
I advise you to look into MVVM pattern as ModelView class should be the one on DataContext of View(Window). ModelView would expose property as SelectedStudent and you would bind to this propery from  your TextBox (Text="{Binding SelectedStudent.FirstName}).